# JList setSelected no longer works after calling setListData a second time

Tags: java, jlist

Alright for starters I have `JList` as a global variable because I am calling it in two different methods.

```
jList.setListData(arrays);
jList.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

So this is the first thing I call in the jList after creating the JList as

```
JList<String> jList = new JList<>();
```

I am then trying to change the JList data on JButton Action

```
chooseBtn.addActionListener(e -> chooseButtonClicked());
```

The problem:

```
private void chooseButtonClicked() {
    jList.setListData(newData);
    jList.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

after the `JList` is updated the index is no longer selected even when I call `setSelectedIndex`

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? If not, try to debug it. The Java source code is available.

Comment: No, I do not have any error except for `e.getSource().getSelectedValue();` returning null on `addListSelectionListener`

Comment: Oh Alright, I found a fix will be answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `setSelectedIndex` wasn't functioning properly because `addListSelectionListener` returned null on `e.getSource().getSelectedValue();`

I have added a check for null

```
if (source instanceof JList) {
    JList < String > jList = (JList) e.getSource();
    if (jList != null) {
        String selectedValue = jList.getSelectedValue();
        if (selectedValue != null) {
            selectedIndex = selectedValue;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to get Selected Value. Cause: NullPointerException");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to get JList. Cause: NullPointerException");
    }
}
```

It prints out `Failed to get Selected Value. Cause: NullPointerException` once and then selects the Index properly without any issues.